# Showing that $\;\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{4}\right)\exp(-x^2+5x-6)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have been set this problem in a calculus class:

$$f(x) = \left(1-\frac{x}{4}\right)\exp(-x^2+5x-6),$$

show that the following holds:

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) =0.$$

Just don't really know where to start with this - I don't think it's L'Hospital's rule because the bottom of the fraction is not differentiable, have tried differentiating $f(x)$ but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: The expression as written tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: Why you think, that limit is zero?

Comment: the expression was missing a minus sign, sorry. corrected.

Comment: Hint: You can write is as $(4-x)/(4e^{x^2+5x-6})$.

Comment: $$
\exp ( - x^2  + 5x - 6) = e^{1/4} \exp \left( { - \left( {x - \frac{5}{2}} \right)^2 } \right) = \frac{{e^{1/4} }}{{\exp \left( {\left( {x - \frac{5}{2}} \right)^2 } \right)}} \le \frac{{e^{1/4} }}{{1 + \left( {x - \frac{5}{2}} \right)^2 }}
$$ since $e^w=1+w+w^2/2 +\cdots \geq 1+w$ for all $w\geq 0$.

Comment: @Bonnaduck thanks, this has nudged me in the right direction definitely. wouldn't the dominator be $4e^{x^2-5x+6}$ though? ie. would all the signs get flipped, not just the sign on the $-x^2$?

Comment: @shineoballo yes, sorry, you’re right, all the signs should change

Comment: @Bonnaduck thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like $\frac{1-\frac{x}{4}}{e^{x^2-5x+6}}$ then apply L'Hospital's rule.